# Accessing property from .cfg file inside a java class

Tags: java, spring, fuseesb

Hi I am trying to use some property that I have defined in the .cfg file in my java class. I am trying to access service.storeurl. This is my property file :

```
 service.protocol=http 
 service.host=localhost 
 service.port=8080
 service.context=newservice
 service.storeurl=[[service.protocol]]\://[[service.host:service.port]]/[[service.context]]/docs
```

When I am using it in java, I am not getting the values for service.protocol, service.host, service.port  n all. This is the error I get :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: [[service.protocol]]://[[service.host:service.port]]/[[service.context]]/docs
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)[:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)[:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)[:1.8.0_45]
    at com.newservice.processor.NewProcessor.process(PingProcessor.java:30)[465:newservice:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:139)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:113)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:95)[207:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:75)[207:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)[82:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)[93:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.5]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)[93:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.5]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:75)[93:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.5]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_45]
```

There are other properties that I have defined in the similar manner which I am able to access in my java class. Only this one property  is not accessible. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

what tools do you use to parse the cfg file? The normal java properties have no mechanism that resolves properties references in double brackets.

So as long as you read the file as a normal properties file, the value of `service.storeurl`is the literal string "[[service.protocol]]://[[service.host:service.port]]/[[service.context]]/docs".

No token replacement is done.